# Apply Tint on ImageButton

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

I am creating an android App which has about 15 ImageButtons. The app will have one activity and several fragments. The onclick event handling of some of the button will be done by fragments and rest will be done by activity.

I want to apply the tint on the buttons when it is pressed. I dont want to use different images for Normal and Pressed state but want to apply the tint programatically as it is a cumbersome to maintain two images for every button.

As I searched on Stackoverflow, there can be multiple ways.
1) Handle the onTouchEvent. On Action_Down event apply the tint and on Action_Up cancel the tint effect. The tint can be applied using the setColorFilter on the button.

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
           ImageButton view = (ImageButton) v;
            view.setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            // Your action here on button click

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                ImageButton view = (ImageButton) v;
                view.clearColorFilter();
                view.invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

The problem with this approach is that since I am handling the button click on different places(Activity and Fragments) I have to do this change at every place which is difficult to maintain.  Also to handle the onClick action, I have put a switch statement in the Action_Up event for every button.

2) Use the Drawables where I create drawable for each button and in the src of the button I specify the drawable file.  I have written a drawable file something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed_drawable" /><!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_image" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_image" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and the  code for btn_pressed_drawable is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/button_image"
    android:tint="#770000"/>
```

But the problem with this approach is that I need to create two files for each buttons and I have about 15 buttons.

Is there a simple way to do it?  I would like to keep the things simple and at a single place.

One more things which i observed is that the result produce by the above two approaches is different. I see the different color while I am applying the same tint value in each case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write colorfilter code `setColorFilter(..)` with `getBackground()`.
After that your code look like below:

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
           ImageButton view = (ImageButton) v;
            view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);//line changed
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            // Your action here on button click

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                ImageButton view = (ImageButton) v;
                view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();//line changed
                view.invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I hope its help you.